# Is it possible to have a python inner 'for' to continue where the outer for stopped?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

For exemple, say i have the following code:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
for c in a: 
    print(c)
    for d in a: 
        print(d)
```

The current output of it is:

```
[1]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[2]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[3]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

My question is whether it is possible to modify this code in a pretty way so that the output becomes like this:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[2]
[3]
[3]
```

In other words if it is possible, in a 'clean python', to have the inner loop to cover the list from the index the outer loop stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and list slicing syntax (`items[start:end:step]`, where `start` defaults to 0, `end` to `items.length`, and `step` to 1) to accomplish this:

```
items = [[1], [2], [3]]
for i, _ in enumerate(items):
    for item in items[i:]:
        print(item)
```

Another interesting (though less efficient) option would be to use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) in conjunction with `sum`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

items = [[1], [2], [3]]
for item in sum(accumulate(([x] for x in items[::-1])), [])[::-1]:
     print(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `range` and iterate over indexes:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
for c in range(len(a)): 
    for d in range(c, len(a)): 
        print(a[d])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `list_iterator` and branch off shallow copies as needed:

```
import copy
ia = iter(a)
for ai in ia:
    print(ai)
    for ai in copy.copy(ia):
        print(ai)

# [1]
# [2]
# [3]
# [2]
# [3]
# [3]
```